# Mern Stack Application Deployment on Heroku (remote: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy a MERN stack application on Heroku and I came by some issues while deployment shown below

```
 npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/build_9fd3be63/client/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_9fd3be63/client/package.json'
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote: npm ERR! enoent
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.mlfBJ/_logs/2021-05-03T03_26_07_032Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 254
remote: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 254
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.mlfBJ/_logs/2021-05-03T03_26_07_059Z-debug.log
```

**Package.json** of Server

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "Umar24129",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.6"
  }
}
```

**Package.json** of Client

```
{
  "name": "react-task-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^3.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

File System (Folders Hierarchy) Below in screenshot.

[image]

I have researched a lot about it and at least couldn't find a proper solution on StackOverflow or Github.
Please Help me solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is npm unable to find the package.json of your client-side. The "heroku-postbuild" script is failing because it has to install and build the client side. If your client side is in another folder I would suggest changing the --prefix tag to something like this:

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false cd .. && cd client_dir && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "Umar24129",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.6"
  }
}
```

So basically you cd out of the server directory (assuming your server package.json is in a server directory in the root) cd into the client directory and then run npm install and build, asumming your client package.json is a folder named `client_dir` in the root directory.

### additional info

please run the postbuild script on your local machine to see if it is running properly, if not then please post the log file which it will specify the location of in the command line.

Comment: I have added the FOlder hierarchy in the question. and Package.json exists and is located in Client folder.

Comment: Hm, then I am not quite sure what is causing this kind of behaviour, can you re-create it on your machine running the postbuild script?

Comment: I did it several many times. I also tried to deploy same project with many other different methods but it wont work even though it works fine on Localhost both build and non build version.

Comment: try setting "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=TRUE" in the script or in the Heroku config vars

Answer (score 0):

My issue here was that Node and NPM versions weren't right. On tutorial, I was watching, NODE had version 8.something and npm 5.something. I changed it to versions on my local machine:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.19.0",
    "npm": "6.14.0"
  },
```

and the application was deployed successfully.